# Color of link doesn't change

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I searched on the web and here and didn't find such case.
The problem is that I can't change the color of the link. I have the following structure:

```
 <ul id="footer_menu">
              <li class="footer_title">Sobre</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sobre nós</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Entre em contato</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contribua</a></li>
 </ul>


a {
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition:  all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

ul#footer_menu li a{
    color: #848587;
}

ul#footer_menu li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

So as you can see, I tried put the most specific path for the links on footer_menu but the color of the links still continue blue and surprising the hover is working correctly.

If anybody could help me. Actually I'm just asking because everything seems be fine. I can't put the color in the first a because no my links will have the same color.

Thank you

Comment: [Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/xt54Z/). Maybe some other style is overriding this one?

Comment: May be there is another rule with higher css specificity.

Comment: It should work with the above css rules. If its not working for you then it might possible that some other css rule overriding the properties for your links

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
<nav id="myslidemenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="what-we-do.html">What we do</a></li>
<li><a  href="our-services.html">Our services</a></li>
<li><a href="who-we-are.html">Who we are</a></li>
<li><a href="case-studies.html">Case studies</a></li>
<li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav ul li a{ 
    color:#000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFBE08;
   -webkit-transition: border-bottom linear 1s;
   -moz-transition: border-bottom linear 1s;
   -o-transition: border-bottom linear 1s;
    transition: border-bottom linear 1s;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul li a:hover{ color:#000; border-bottom:1px solid #000; }
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not answer the question either. The CSS in the question should work as-is. No need for new ways to achieve same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul#footer_menu li a{
    color: #848587 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at  **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt54Z/1/)** it works completely fine

```
ul#footer_menu li a{
    color: red;
}

ul#footer_menu li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: @Vucko who wrote ul #footer_menu li a??

Comment: You guys can explain intead of coming and downvoting :( We are trying to help and may sometimes be wrong,so you guys can help us improve instead of downvoting

Comment: All you did was remove the `ul`; that does not answer the question.

Comment: Of course it is working :) it will also work if you add the ul back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52012/discussion-between-salman-a-and-richa)